# Cannot read property 'total' of undefined

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

If i do not have data for current month then i get following error

> Cannot read property 'total' of undefined"

Stuff i have tried

```
$group: { _id: null,
        total: { $sum:{ $cond : [ {$eq : [ "$cost", undefined ]} , 0,'$cost'] }}
        }
```

below is my current code

```
var currentDate = new Date(); 
var currMonth = currentDate.getMonth()+1;    
Spending.aggregate([
    { $project: { month: { $month: '$date' }, cost: true } },
    { $match: { month: currMonth } },
    { $group: {
        _id: null,
        total: { $sum: '$cost'}
        }
    }
]).exec().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    res.status(200).render('index', { total: result });
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json(err);
});
```

For example if have this 1 entry in my db 
{
date: 2019-05-10,
cost: 10
}

In this case if currMonth  is **05** then total is **10** 
Now if the currMonth is any thing except **5** it is giving the error above 
whereas the expected output was **0**

Comment: There is nothing in the above code which is throwing the error you have shown.

Comment: I get the following error if i try to render the index page. But if we write res.status(200).json(result)  it returns blank instead i am expecting 0